# Auto Login after email verification in djoser using JWTAuthentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, djoser

I'm using djoser in my django project and JWTAuthentication for authentication.

I want to auto login user (i.e. create access and refresh token) after verifying email and redirecting to `ACTIVATION_URL` defined in settings.

The problem is that they are 2 different actions each with its own endoint and view:

1- `TokenObtainPairView` which authenticates user and creates the tokens.

2- djoser `activation` function which just activates user if email is verified.

My thought is to customize the activation view, authenticate user from there but also create and send the tokens, how to do so ? and Is it a good approach?